# U-shape waves with musgrave texture node in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor

I would like to make some *U*-shape waves like the ones I drawn in yellow on the picture below :
[image]

Now I'm trying to found a way to make some radial waves with the musgrave texture node in cycles trough it's vector input. I didn't succed so far, but I found a way to make something who looks some like radial wave,
[image]

the problems on the picture above are, first off that I lost the ability to change the scale, second it looks radial only around the origin point. Moreover I really would like to know how to solve this problem with the vector input, because I hope it will fit better with my linear waves and it would also help me to solve some other problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok I think I found *one* acceptable solution :
[image]

first, I solve the scale problem with the coloramp at the exit of the musgrave texture node.

second, for the vector, I normalize it. If I'm not wrong, I guess between the range (for x and y) [-1,1] it would give a good result, beyond I guess it will not, so scaling the vector would not leads to a good solution. However, I'm not sure at all, so if somebody can confirm or infirm my assertion I would appreciate that.

Second solution, I guess it's *the* solution!
[image]

*x* is used as an angular variable, *y* is used as a radial variable. The key was to use gradient texture, these nodes give bounded values, so mapping can help to scale the disk. This solution answer fully to my needs, first it uses vector input and second I can scale musgrave.

(My musgrave setting is not periodic)

I shall wait 48H before selecting my answer as solution, so anybody can post some solution, maybe more convenient than mine!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I was able to get the scaling by putting a **Mapping** node before the **Separate XYZ**, so if you use this node setup:[image]

I played around with the *location* and *scale* and *power* options getting this result:
[image]

Which sounds like what you are looking for.

Comment: your solution leads to exactly the same problems. all you did by scaling is zooming at the origin. The power of 2 is nothing less but to calculate the distance, if you use another power you can stretch and I guess getting some weird behaviour with an odd power and negative coordinates.

Comment: I just want to rectify something, it's not the actual distance, but the squared distance...